# Golang gorm mocking

Tags: database, testing, go, mocking, go-gorm

I am using [gorm](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm) in my projects. Can I mock this database orm for testing without database connection? The problem we have CI tools where I don't have database or database with enough data for testing. The other way, I don't want to setup a database for every time I'm testing, because in these cases the CI tool create every time a container just for run the tests.

Whet is the best way for testing database related methods? I am using dependency injection in my solutions so it is easy to replace the database with a mocked database. But the gorm have many orm related function.

This is a handler for example:

```
func tokenIntrospectionHandler(db *gorm.DB) http.HandlerFunc {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        defer req.Body.Close()
        token := req.FormValue("token")
        var resp Response
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(resp)
    })
}
```

Comment: You can set up a net conn in your test case to respond to specific test queries. Also it doesn't appear that the tolenIntrospectionHandler uses the DB at all so Im not sure how to guide you on writing a test case.

Comment: I'm not familiar with gorm and directly use golang's "sql" package. But to test my database facing code, I have introduced interfaces which are naturally implemented by the concrete types declared in the "sql" package and then implemented my own mock objects that implement those interfaces. Everywhere else in the code I use those interfaces instead of concrete types. I'd then inject the mocks during testing.

Answer (score 4):

for unit tests, this looks pretty good to mock `gorm.DB`: https://github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock

Here's an example from their site. You just creates the mock, then the DB, sets the expectations for the method calls, then run your code under testing and finally check if the expectations are met.

```golang
// a successful case
func TestShouldUpdateStats(t *testing.T) {
    db, mock, err := sqlmock.New()
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("an error '%s' was not expected when opening a stub database connection", err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    mock.ExpectBegin()
    mock.ExpectExec("UPDATE products").WillReturnResult(sqlmock.NewResult(1, 1))
    mock.ExpectExec("INSERT INTO product_viewers").WithArgs(2, 3).WillReturnResult(sqlmock.NewResult(1, 1))
    mock.ExpectCommit()

    // now we execute our method
    if err = recordStats(db, 2, 3); err != nil {
        t.Errorf("error was not expected while updating stats: %s", err)
    }

    // we make sure that all expectations were met
    if err := mock.ExpectationsWereMet(); err != nil {
        t.Errorf("there were unfulfilled expectations: %s", err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if you are using clean architecture just mock your repository its a lot better

Comment: Repositories are good, but they don't allow for flexible queries. e.g. Having a GetUser but maybe I dont want every field included, it's tricky to do that with repositories and add a lot of uneeded complexity which won't be tested because repositories themselves will be using the database itself. So, yes while you will be able to test the "service" (per clean arch) you won't be able to test the complex structure of the repository, or if you won't make it complex you lose the flexibility and efficiency of sql queries. So you dont really win anything in this case. At least thats my perspective.